# Select the price in a jquery array and add to Total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i a have a combo box where i can choose specific vehicle, each has engine size, name and price wrapped in an array.
If vehicle 1 chosen i want to add their price to the total amount.
Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<select id="selector" onChange="Expedisi(this);">
            <option>Select product</option>
          <optgroup label="Sedan">
            <option value="Lancer EX">Lancer EX 1.6 / 2.0</option>
            <option value="Lancer EX GT">Lancer EX GT</option>
          <optgroup label="Sport">
            <option value="Lancer Evolution X">Lancer Evolution X</option>
          <optgroup label="SUV">
            <option value="Outlander">Outlander</option>
        </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = { 
    "Lancer EX" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/lancerex.png" , label: "Lancer EX " , engine: "1.6 L" , price :"16500" },
    "Lancer EX GT" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/gt.png", label: "Lancer EX GT", engine: "2.0 L" , price: "22000"},
    "Lancer Evolution X" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/evox.jpg", label: "Evolution X", engine:"2.0L Turbocharged", price: "85000" },
    "Outlander" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/outlander.jpg", label: "Outlander", engine: "2.0 L" , price : "33000" },
};
```

I want to add the price of the chosen vehicle from the combo box to the Total which is 0 at first.
Thank you.

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the correct vehicle in your object by using the selected value as the property name.
Example:

`data[$(this).val()].price`

```js
var data = { 
    "Lancer EX" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/lancerex.png" , label: "Lancer EX " , engine: "1.6 L" , price :"16500" },
    "Lancer EX GT" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/gt.png", label: "Lancer EX GT", engine: "2.0 L" , price: "22000"},
    "Lancer Evolution X" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/evox.jpg", label: "Evolution X", engine:"2.0L Turbocharged", price: "85000" },
    "Outlander" : { img: "cars/mitsubishi/outlander.jpg", label: "Outlander", engine: "2.0 L" , price : "33000" },
};

var total = 0;

$('#selector').on('change', function() {
    total = data[$(this).val()].price;
    console.log(total);

    $('#thetotal').text("The total is: " + total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selector">
  <option>Select product</option>
  <optgroup label="Sedan">
  <option value="Lancer EX">Lancer EX 1.6 / 2.0</option>
  <option value="Lancer EX GT">Lancer EX GT</option>
  <optgroup label="Sport">
  <option value="Lancer Evolution X">Lancer Evolution X</option>
  <optgroup label="SUV">
  <option value="Outlander">Outlander</option>
</select>

<p id="thetotal"></p>
```

Comment: Its working but if i choose another it adds up to sum, i want 1 selection for the total, meaning if i choose 25000 then 85000, i dont want their sum , i want the last selection.

Comment: Then you just need to remove the `total +`. See update

Comment: i solved it: instead of `total = total + Number(data[$(this).val()].price);` i used `total = Number(data[$(this).val()].price);`

Comment: Yes this works like magic ! can you show me how to print the total on screen rather than console or alert. I mean like the total is:...
Here is what i've done `<p id="thetotal> </p>` and in javascript `document.getElementById("thetotal").innerHTML = "The total is: " + total;` 
but doesnt seem to work...

Comment: That should work fine but since you are using jQuery, you can do it in a more succinct manner. See update.

Comment: if you can set up a live demo showing the issue(JSFiddle.net) then I may be able to help. It's not possible to know why it isn't working without seeing your code.

Comment: No need for that it works perfectly, the problem was i was putting `$('#thetotal').text("The total is: " + total);` after `})` therefore it was always giving 0 no matter what my selection is.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Expedisi function like below -

```
 var data = {
     "Lancer EX": {
         img: "cars/mitsubishi/lancerex.png",
         label: "Lancer EX ",
         engine: "1.6 L",
         price: "16500"
     },
     "Lancer EX GT": {
         img: "cars/mitsubishi/gt.png",
         label: "Lancer EX GT",
         engine: "2.0 L",
         price: "22000"
     },
     "Lancer Evolution X": {
         img: "cars/mitsubishi/evox.jpg",
         label: "Evolution X",
         engine: "2.0L Turbocharged",
         price: "85000"
     },
     "Outlander": {
         img: "cars/mitsubishi/outlander.jpg",
         label: "Outlander",
         engine: "2.0 L",
         price: "33000"
     },
 };


 function Expedisi(elem) {
     var total = 0;
     total += parseInt(data[elem.value].price, 10);
     console.log(total);

 }
```

Comment: i changed the view of the array, more readable for sure like this, but as for total, i mentioned before i dont want the totals to add up... i want only the price of the car to show up